# Number of trees with a given degree sequence.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In my quest to find the number of labeled trees with given degree sequence I've come across the following document [LINK!](http://www.math-inf.uni-greifswald.de/mathe/images/Wandt/preprints/cieslik-countrees.pdf), in which in theorem 4.3 the number of labeled trees for given degree sequence is given as:

$$\dfrac{(n-2)!}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}(g_i-1)!}$$

The proof in this document doesn't explain in a any way how to get to this conclusion, there's only an inductive proof that this in fact holds.

Does anyone how this formula was derived?

Comment: The link mentioned above cannot be accessed unless and until I have logged in to the respective website, Can you please do something about it. I truly wanted to go through the proof once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A modified version of The Prufer proof will work. For each labeled tree $T$, construct a sequence of length $n-2$ as follows:

At each step, pick the leaf with the largest label and record its degree in the sequence. Stop when only one edge is left. In the resulting sequence,  the value $g_i$ appears  $(g_i-1)$ times. You can prove by induction that this mapping between trees and sequences is a bijection. Hence, you get your formula.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this problem for a paper, in the particular case of full plane trees (nodes with ordered children). We call the formula for the array of coefficients **submultinomial**, because it's of the form: $$\frac 1 {k_1+k_2+\ldots} \binom{k_1+k_2+\ldots}{k_1, k_2, \ldots}$$

Those aren't always a natural number, though the subset in the arrays of interest, which count objects of a type, are of course always natural numbers.

The earliest appearance I've found is McMahon, 1894 (almost), and then Capelli, 1907 and Van Orstrand, 1910, followed by Birkeland, Belardinelli, Mellin, Mayr and others in the 1920s and 1930s. A 1D projection of this array of unbounded dimension appears in Schroeder, 1871 (the little Schroeder numbers) and a 2D projection in Cayley, 1891.  It's apparently first interpreted combinatorically in Erdelyi and Etherington, 1940, then independently in Tutte, 1960 and Kreweras, 1972. It appears in Sands, 1978, in handbook Riordan, 1968 and in textbook Goulden and Jackson, 1983, among other places. Recent papers include Rhoades, 2011, who explicitly counts trees of a type, and Schuetz and Whieldon, 2016. Gessel's 2016 Lagrange Inversion paper has the coefficient appearing in a series reversion derivation.

I'm actually conflating two similar arrays in the above.  One counts the number of a given type of subdivision of a roofed polygon.  Such subdivisions have a bijection into full plane trees with no unary nodes (because there are no 2-gons). So that array, which appears in series reversions, is slightly less general than the array that includes unary nodes. In our paper we write the less general one, which we call the **generalized Catalans**, as $C_{\bf m}=C[m_2, m_3, \ldots]$, starting the index at 2, the type indicating a subdivision into $m_2$ triangles, $m_3$ quadrilaterals, etc. The more general one is $K[m_1,m_2,m_3,\ldots]$, $m_1$ unary nodes, $m_2$ binary nodes, etc, with $$C[m_2, m_3, \ldots]=K[0,m_2, m_3, \ldots].$$ ($K$ because I found Kreweras before Tutte.)  We don't include $m_0$, which is determined by the other $m_i$ as related to the number of vertices.  We have Euler's polytope formula $V-E+F=2$ (or $1$ for polygons) in play; in fact the coefficient can be written $$C_{\bf m} = \dfrac{(E_{\bf m} - 1)! }{(V_{\bf m} - 1)! \,  m_2 !  \,  m_3 ! \cdots }$$
and similarly for $K_{\bf m}$.

I'll save my fairly extensive bibliography for my paper, but you can start with Erdelyi et al., Tutte and Kreweras. Tutte addresses trees directly.

Erdelyi, A. and Etherington, I. M. H., 1940, Some problems of non-associative combinations (2), 10.1017/S0950184300002640

https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/4216D1DDB6DF23ADF56FBF3A8C7A6A7B/S0950184300002640a.pdf/some-problems-of-non-associative-combinations-2.pdf

Kreweras, Germain, 1972, On the Non-crossing Partitions of a Cycle,  2005 translation by Berton A. Earnshaw.

https://users.math.msu.edu/users/earnshaw/research/kreweras.pdf

W. T. Tutte, 1964, The Number of Planted Plane Trees with a Given Partition, The American Mathematical Monthly, 71(3), pp. 272-277.

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2312183

Comment: "Submultinomial" doesn't sound right. The formula in the question is just a straightforward multinomial: since $g_1 + \dots + g_n = 2(n-1)$ by the handshake lemma, $(g_1 - 1) + \dots + (g_n - 1) = n-2$, so the formula is just $\binom{n-2}{g_1-1,\dots,g_n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I've recently come across a paper of yours in my literature search.  

The formula for counting full plane trees of a given degree sequence or roofed polygon dissections of a given type vector is definitely a submultinomial array, e.g. the Catalans.  See any of the references or more recently https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272420/1-s2.0-S0195669810X00099/1-s2.0-S0195669810001460/main.pdf or https://msp.org/involve/2016/9-2/involve-v9-n2-p04-s.pdf.  

It perhaps comes down to the definition of n or the degree sequence but alas the link doesn't work.

Comment: When we talk "full plane trees", do you perhaps consider different plane embeddings of the same tree to be different? I can definitely see that having a Catalan-like result.

Comment: Ah, yes, that must be the difference.  I'm referring to full plane trees, each node with ordered children.  Since the ordering matters, there are indeed trees isomorphic as graphs that are counted as different.