# Number of connected components of an induced subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph ($V$,$E$) with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Suppose it has $l$ connected components, labeled by $1,2,\dots,l$, with sizes $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_l$ respectively. Now we arbitrarily pick $k$ out of the $n$ vertices, say $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_k$ , and consider the induced subgraph of $G$ on these $k$ vertices. Is there a way to calculate the number of connected components of this induced subgraph?

This math stackexchange question might be related [Numbers of ways $k - 1$ edges to be added to $k$ connected components to make the graph connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640205/numbers-of-ways-k-1-edges-to-be-added-to-k-connected-components-to-make-th).

Comment: Is there a way to calculate them? Yes, just calculate them. If $A_i$ and $A_j$ are in a connected component of the original graph, then they are in the same connected component of the subgraph. Are you maybe interested in the distribution of the number of connected components in the subgraph?