# Find number of trees with $\deg(v) = 1$ or $\deg(v) = 3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Find number of trees where
$$ \forall{v}, \text{ }\deg(v) \in \left\{1,3 \right\} $$
Generally I have idea for recurrence there:

$$t_n = n\left( t_{n-1} + \sum_{a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z_+} \wedge a+b+c = n-3} t_a t_b t_c \right) $$

but it is too hard to solve so there is probably tricky observation which could help to write a explicit pattern for that.

Comment: Is "number of trees" up to isomorphism, or are the trees labeled?

Comment: Assuming you mean labelled, actually it's simple as if we let k_1, k_3 be number of vertices deg 1 and 3 resp. then k_1 + k_3 = |V| and k_1 + 3k_3 = 2|V| - 2, so we can deduce k_1 and k_3, combine this with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612927/number-of-trees-with-a-given-degree-sequence. And you will get a nice closed expression

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the tree has $n$ vertices, $k$ of which are of degree $3$.  By the Handshaking Lemma, $$3k+(n-k)=2(n-1)\implies k={n-2\over2}$$ so $t_n=0$ if $n$ is odd.

I had originally thought that there would only be one isomorphism class when $n$ is even, but this isn't so.  I had just tried very small examples.

I still don't have a full solution, but here's another idea.  Suppose T is an admissible tree.  Call the subgraph of T induced by all the vertices of T the "$3$-subgraph" of T.  If G is the $3$-subgraph of T, then G is a tree of maximal degree $2$.  Furthermore there is only one way to get from G to an admissible tree whose $3$-subgraph is G; attach a leaf to each vertex of degree $2$ and two leaves to each vertex of degree $1$.

If I'm not mistaken, when $n$ is even, this shows that $t_n$ is the number of trees on ${n-2\over2}$ vertices with maximum degree $3$.  Not sure if this helps, though.

**EDIT** I used [nauty](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) to calculate the number of $3$-valent trees on $n$ vertices for $n=1,\dots,20$ and plugged the result into OEIS to find [A000672](https://oeis.org/A000672).  The "formulas" given on the page seem way too complicated to come up with during an exam.  Perhaps we're supposed to be counting labeled trees rather than isomorphism classes?

Comment: @Karl Yes, I just found two with $12$ vertices, and edited my answer.

Comment: Another observation: the tree is uniquely determined by the subgraph formed by the degree-3 vertices, which is an arbitrary tree with all degrees $\le 3$, so this problem reduces to counting those trees of size $k$.

Comment: Interesting observation with $deg(v) = 3$ - it can immediately remove lot of cases. This task comes from old exam and I suspect that the level of this task is similar to other tasks - so I still thinking about solution which doesn't contains a lot of "if then" but each observation is really helpful, thanks!